# Sending records to cross account Kinesis stream from Lambda

Tags: boto3, amazon-kinesis

I'm trying to send events to kinesis stream in another account(**Account B**) using the boto3 api from Lambda fxn in "**Account A**"

```
kinesis = boto3.client('kinesis', )

response = kinesis.put_record(
        StreamName="account-b-stream-name",
        Data=data,
        PartitionKey="partitionkey")
```

This results in the following error

```
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the PutRecord operation: User: arn:aws:sts::<AccountA>:assumed-role/putrecords-staging-kinesis-dev-lambdaRole/putrecords-staging-kinesis-dev-hello is not authorized to perform: kinesis:PutRecord on resource: arn:aws:kinesis:eu-west-1:<AccountA>:stream/events_kinesis_staging
```

The boto3 seems to send the records to events_kinesis_staging and makes assumption that it is still in **Account A** where the lambda is running.

How can I explictly specify the account id of the stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an IAM user in Account B with Kinesis permissions. Then, create access keys.

Then in your lambda function you can add environment variables `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` and put in values from the access key. This should get you going.

However, a better way to go about it would be to set up a cross account delegation role.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html